# Cómo traer la informacion de un Promise {<pending>} React JS React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Estoy trayendo una informacion de los parametros de la URL y unos datos de una consulta a una API en el loader como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image]

Llamo los datos con el useloaderData

[image]

pero cuando le doy el console log para ver que datos me trae me trae los siguiente:

[image]

¿Como hago para acceder a esa informacion y desplegarla en el DOM?

No se si estoy retornando mal los valores o si los estoy llamando mal en el useloaderData, pero si retorno solo 1 dato en el loader ahi si me trae el array bien.. necesito ayuda.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido al sitio, este es [es.so], por favor escribe tu pregunta solo en español, si la deseas escribir en inglés puedes usar el sitio [so]. Recuerda realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask]. El código se pone como texto. no como imagen. Aun así es probable que tu problema se solucione con un simple `const contenidos = await obtenerCapacitaciones()`. Si no es así, arregla tu pregunta usando el botón de [edit] y agrega la mayor cantidad de detalles posibles relacionados con el problema para poder ayudarte

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, no habia visto que me faltaba el await.